# Formatting String For Network Request (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, string, react-native, ecmascript-6

Here is my dilemma:
I need to format the body of my POST request exactly like the example below, and the quotation marks are very important.

```
'{"url":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/de/Bananavarieties.jpg"}'
```

Although, I would eventually like to pass a value into the url instead of having it hardcoded in.

I have tried using:

```
const uriInQuotes = "'"+uri+"'";
'{"url":+uriInQuotes+}'
```

But the format is still not correct. Anyway I can go about doing this? With the quotation marks properly formatted?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Possibly try escaping the double quotes like this: "\'" instead of using "'"

Comment: json.stringify is the only correct way to create json with javascript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to convert your object to a valid JSON string which is what it looks you need to POST.

```
let requestBody = { url: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/de/Bananavarieties.jpg' };

return JSON.stringify(requestBody);
```